# Is it possible for moderators to move answers from one question to another?

Tags: discussion, answers, moderators, duplicate-questions

I've just been reading this question: [How can a single developer make use of Agile Methods?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/141818/32008). And after refreshing, I saw it was closed for being a duplicate to [Agile for the Solo Developer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/220/32008). I don't discuss the fact that those are duplicates, they clearly are.

However, I feel [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/141821/32008) from user @DXM to the closed question is way more insightful, well written and thoughtful than most other answers to the other question. I was thinking it's a shame this answer gets destroyed/hidden because the question is closed.

So, is moving answers something that can be done, or has it been already discussed maybe ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The questions can be merged which will transfer all the answers from the duplicate to the the original.

Comment: "can" ? You mean it's an option you have but it's not automatically done ?

Comment: That's right. It's not automatic.

Comment: Well I hope you'll consider it, thanks for your answer.

Comment: If it makes any difference, I support @Jalayn's request to merge the questions.